# show login page for a second when routering other pages reactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, firebase, authentication

I use this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4EsP6rovwk&t=1s to create an Auth for my website,
i basically copied his code the only change is that I route after successful login to different page.

the problem is that after login my home page is shown, but when I'm pressing buttons to route for other pages, before the other page is shown I see for a second the login page.

this is the code of the auth - I believe it connect to the problem (before this my website has worked well).

Edit:
i try to figure out what's the problem and I've noticed that when i'm using link everything's fine, but when using href there's a problem.
(And that's what I did in my website).
So... does anyone know why href makes this issue?

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fire from './Fire';
import SearchAppBar from '../components/appBar';
import Login from './login';


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = ({
      user: null,
    });
    this.authListener = this.authListener.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener();
  }

  authListener() {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null });
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>{this.state.user ? ( <SearchAppBar/>) : (<Login />)}</div>)
}
}

export default App;
```

login.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import fire from './Fire';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((u)=>{
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  signup(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((u)=>{
    }).then((u)=>{console.log(u)})
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <div className="col-md-6">
       <form>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
       <input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} type="email" name="email" 
       class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter 
       email" />
       <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else. 
       </small>
      </div>
       <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} type="password" name="password" 
       class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" onClick={this.login} className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      <button onClick={this.signup} style={{marginLeft: '25px'}} className="btn btn- 
       success">Signup</button>
       </form>

 </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Login;
```

Thank you all guys!!

Comment: How do you check for authenticated user in other components?

Comment: I do not check. I mean... my website was just some pages you can route to by buttons and everything was fine. Now i added the components above, and the <SearchAppBar/> component (which you're lead to after login) is the same main page as the one which worked well before. I dont check users and stuff their